# Calculating sum of ordered list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to find out how to return a sum of several values given in a order list of dictionaries

```
menu = {
    1: {"name": 'espresso',
        "price": 1.99},
    2: {"name": 'coffee', 
        "price": 2.50},
    3: {"name": 'cake', 
        "price": 2.79},
    4: {"name": 'soup', 
        "price": 4.50},
    5: {"name": 'sandwich',
        "price": 4.99}
}


def calculate_subtotal(order):
  
return subtotal

def take_order():
    display_menu()
    order = []
    count = 1
    for i in range(3):
        item = input('Select menu item number ' + str(count) + ' (from 1 to 5): ')
        count += 1
        order.append(menu[int(item)])
    return order
```

- def calculate_subtotal(order) should accept one argument which is the order list and return the sum
  of the prices of the items in the order list.
- Do I have to use a for loop to iterate through the values and sum each value?
- How do I access the dictionaries inside the list?

Comment: Use the `sum()` function with a generator as the argument.

Comment: you can try ```sum(menu[i]["price"] for i in order)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say a person orders the following:

```py
orders = [
    {"name": "espresso", "price": 1.99},
    {"name": "espresso", "price": 1.99},
    {"name": "soup", "price": 4.99},
]
```

You now have a `list` of `dict`. Indexing into the `list` returns a reference to a dictionary. For example:

```py
first_order = orders[0]
print(first_order)
```

Would print:

```py
{'name': 'espresso', 'price': 1.99}
```

Using that knowledge, you can loop through the orders like so:

```py
total = 0.0
for order in orders:
    total += order["price"]
```

Each `order` will be a `dict` like you saw above.

You can also use a comprehension if you're comfortable with them.

```py
total = sum(order["price"] for order in orders)
```